# GraphRequest not returning details even when the Access Token is passed

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to get user details by using Facebook Graph API, but i am not getting the result which was expected. To make my self more clear i am stating the steps that i have followed.

1. Integrated Facebook API with the Android App.
2. Set Permission for the details that are needed.
3. Requesting for token.
4. After Receiving the token again requesting for details using GraphRequest.
   But the onCompleted Method in GraphRequest is not getting invoked.

Here is my code snippet.

```
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, loginResult.getAccessToken().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("test", loginResult.getAccessToken().toString());
            GraphRequest graphRequest = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.d("response", response.toString());
                }
            });
        }
  }
```

The Log which is with the key "response" id not getting printed, in clear the GrapRequest is not invoking the method onComplete.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Above code is not executing GraphRequest because you are not calling executeAsync() method on graphRequest object.

**graphRequest.executeAsync(); // You have to add this line to your code**

After Modification you code looks like

```
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, loginResult.getAccessToken().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("test", loginResult.getAccessToken().toString());
                GraphRequest graphRequest = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                        Log.d("response", response.toString());
                    }
                });

             graphRequest.executeAsync(); // You have to add this line to your code

            }
      }
```